# Using register variables in recursion?

Tags: c, recursion

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void main()

    {

        register int x = 0;

        if (x < 2)

        {

            x++;

            main();

        }

    }
```

Output:

`segmentation fault`

Why I am getting segmentation fault?

Comment: You're overflowing the stack.

Comment: @larsmans in C++ it is undefined but not in C

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: indeed, my mistake.

Comment: perhaps because you combine register storage class with recursion; I assume you know the effects/implications of each one of them separate; now you have an idea about combining them.

Comment: `register` has nothing to do with the reported error; it's there just to confuse everybody. A better question to ask would be about the same code, but without `register`. (downvoted)

Answer (score 4):

Register has nothing to do with this error. It is just a type of storage class.

Even without register it shows core dump.

The reason for the core dump is stack overflow becaz of recursion.

Try by using printf("%d",x) after x++ and before main();

if (x < 2)

```
    {

        x++;
        printf("%d",x);

        main();

    }
```

The reason for stack gets overflow is every time you called main() in recursion the x re initialized to 0, thus always satisfies the condition `if(x < 2)` and results in stack overflow.

Try to use static storage class to avoid this error.

Answer (score 1):

Because 'register' is an advisory to the compiler, which compilers are free to ignore. They say "put this variable in a register, please" but it doesn't change the scope of `x` in your code. Which means main will be called, and then create a local variable called x reserving space on the stack, initialise it to zero, etc, etc, etc.

Comment: In this particular example, even if the compiler wanted to follow your `register` hint, it could only do that for a handful of levels before it would run out of spare registers and be forced to use the stack.

Comment: what would happen if i were to write static register int x = 0 is this even valid just curious.

Comment: @tesseract - Not a valid syntax. Will throw compilation error.

Comment: @AShelly I doubt it'd do that as it'd have to unwind the recursion somehow so it can use more than 1 register